# Приложение для записи видео с экрана для телефонов/планшетов под ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, objective-c

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как на ios можно записать видео с экрана пользователя (желательно используя swift).

Записывать требуется:

1. Работу с браузером (для этого вроде подходит ReplayKit - для записи экрана, WKWebView и WebKit - для работы с браузером).
2. Работу с другими приложениями (здесь как я понял ReplayKit уже не подходит - при переходе в другое приложение запись прерывается).

Возможна ли вообще запись экрана вне приложения? можно ли как-то использовать встроенный Screen Recording в моем приложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Остановился в итоге на добавлении кнопки во вью контроллер и записи через нее

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let broadcastPicker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 350, width: 80, height: 80))
    broadcastPicker.preferredExtension = nil
    
    view.addSubview(broadcastPicker)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Запись экрана вне приложения невозможна. Встроенный Screen Recording в личном приложении использовать нельзя – только ReplayKit.

Comment: но можно ведь, например, добавить RPSystemBroadcastPickerView и запустить запись из него

Comment: RPSystemBroadcastPickerView тоже из ReplayKit.